# (Softlayer API) How to set Time to Live in cloud storage in softlayer

Tags: cdn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I refered this document, 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/Object-Storage-CDN/Set-Time-Live-TTL

my request headers are like below but I get 400 error with this message "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8080/cloud/objectstorage"

```
'X-Context' : 'cdn',
'X-Cdn-Ttl' : 3600,
'Accept' : 'application/json',
'X-Auth-Token' : token
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this curl:

```
curl -i -XPOST -H "X-Cdn-Ttl: 3600" -H "X-Context: cdn"  -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_XXXX" https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_6d6s56a-1665-4135-b145-8584d3427299/407608/mycontainer

Replace your token, URL
        The value 407608 is the ID of your account
        mycontainer is the name of the container you wish to edit the Time
```

Regards